# How to put up and down arrow just above dots in the slideshow of forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on making a slideshow of forms. Here is my working [codepen link](https://codepen.io/jainaman23/pen/owXeLp). As you can see I have two dots on the right side which if I click then it opens another form. Now I want to put an up arrow just above those dots and down arrow just below those dots.

For example as shown in this [image](https://postimg.org/image/4isaog1mx/). I am trying to replicate exactly like this image and as you can see there is a up arrow just above those dots and down arrow just below those dots and they are perfectly aligned in one vertical line and  also their color is orange I believe. I want to do exactly like that. How can I achieve this? I am already using font-awesome css in my actual code, do I have to use that here?

Below is my HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SlidesJS Standard Code Example</title>
  <meta name="description" content="SlidesJS is a simple slideshow plugin for jQuery. Packed with a useful set of features to help novice and advanced developers alike create elegant and user-friendly slideshows.">
  <meta name="author" content="Nathan Searles">

  <!-- SlidesJS Required (if responsive): Sets the page width to the device width. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- CSS for slidesjs.com example -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- End CSS for slidesjs.com example -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Optional: If you'd like to use this design -->
  <style>
    body {
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      font: normal 15px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #232525;
    }

    #slides,
    #slides2,
    #slides3 {
      display: none;
      margin-bottom:50px;
    }

    .slidesjs-navigation {
      margin-top:3px;
    }

    .slidesjs-previous {
      margin-right: 5px;
      float: left;
    }

    .slidesjs-next {
      margin-right: 5px;
      float: left;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination {
      margin: 6px 0 0;
      float: right;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li {
      float: left;
      margin: 0 1px;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a {
      display: block;
      width: 13px;
      height: 0;
      padding-top: 13px;
      background-image: url("https://s16.postimg.org/pt4k43i9x/pagination.png");
      background-position: 0 0;
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a.active,
    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover.active {
      background-position: 0 -13px
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {
      background-position: 0 -26px
    }
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden
    }
  </style>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Optional-->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: These styles are required if you'd like a responsive slideshow -->
  <style>
    #slides {
      display: none
    }

    .container {
      margin: 0 auto
    }

    /* For tablets & smart phones */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      body {
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
      }
      .container {
        width: auto
      }
    }

    /* For smartphones */
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
      .container {
        width: auto
      }
    }

    /* For smaller displays like laptops */
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
      .container {
        width: 724px
      }
    }

    /* For larger displays */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      .container {
        width: 1170px
      }
    }
  </style>
  <!-- SlidesJS Required: -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav">
   <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/ojd13poal/northman_wordmark_CMYK.png">
   <nav>
      <ul>
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#"><b>INSURANCE</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
               <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL</i></a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#"><i>CORPORATE</i></a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="our-story">OUR STORY</li>
         <li class="login-signup">Log In | Sign up</li>
         <li class="get-covered">GET <strong style="font-style:italic">COVERED</strong>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</div>  
  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->
  <!-- The container is used to define the width of the slideshow -->
  <div class="container">
   <h3>INSURANCE FORM</h3>
   <h4><i>BASIC DETAILS</i></h4>
   <br>    
    <div id="slides" class="container-fluid" >
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>FIRST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 1">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>LAST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>EMAIL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>COUNTRY</label>
            <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>PROVINCE</label>
            <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>CITY</label>
            <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>FIRST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>LAST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>EMAIL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>COUNTRY</label>
            <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>PROVINCE</label>
            <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>CITY</label>
            <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
            <a href="#" class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <!-- End SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jQuery -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jquery.slides.js -->
  <script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Initialize SlidesJS with a jQuery doc ready -->
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 800,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false
      });

      /*
        To have multiple slideshows on the same page
        they just need to have separate IDs
      */
      $('#slides2').slidesjs({
        width: 800,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false,
        start: 3,
        play: {
          auto: true
        }
      });

      $('#slides3').slidesjs({
        width: 800,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false
      });
    });
  </script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of these elements

```
<a href="#" class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation">
   <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>
</a>
<a href="#" class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation">
   <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
</a>
```

position these elements absolute align them to right.

https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/weaxqj?editors=1100

visit the codepen link here

Comment: I already have these elements. What I am supposed to do with those? Can you provide codepen link or jsfiddle so that I can understand better.

Comment: thanks.. also how can I make those arrows orange just like it is in my actual image along with those dots.. I am trying to replicate that image.

Answer (score 0):

You cas use :after and :before pseudo elements to put arrows before first dot and after last. Just set dots positions to relative and in :after/before add arrow in content and set it absolute position.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by after and before here. Can you provide codepen link or jsfiddle so that I can understand better?